# How to compare 2 arrays and get the difference

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays I want to compare and then collect the difference out.

I am only showing 2 elements in each array. Normally each array contains more than 80000 elements

Array1 output (`$Memcooltransactions`)

```
    Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [zipcode] => 0000 [city] => 23593 Vellinge, Sverige [numberofuniqmembers] => 11 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [zipcode] => 4212 [city] => CPH, Denmark [numberofuniqmembers] => 2 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 )
```

Array1 output (`$result`)

```
    Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [zipcode] => 0460 [city] => Nordskali, Færøerne [numberofuniqmembers] => 1 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [zipcode] => 4212 [city] => CPH, Denmark [numberofuniqmembers] => 2 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 )
```

Desired output:

```
 [0] => Array ( [zipcode] => 0000 [city] => 23593 Vellinge, Sverige [numberofuniqmembers] => 11 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [zipcode] => 0460 [city] => Nordskali, Færøerne [numberofuniqmembers] => 1 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0
```

This is how i tried:

```
$result2 = array_diff_assoc($Memcooltransactions, $result1);
```

But i am getting this output: (`$result2`)

```
 Array (
    [0] => Array ( [zipcode] => 0000 [city] => 23593 Vellinge, Sverige [numberofuniqmembers] => 11 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 
    [1] => Array ( [zipcode] => 4212 [city] => CPH, Denmark [numberofuniqmembers] => 2 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0
    [2] => Array ( [zipcode] => 0460 [city] => Nordskali, Færøerne [numberofuniqmembers] => 1 [numberofuniqspisesteder] => 0 
   )
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If the arrays are built from a database request, better to handle this in the DB query

Comment: Yes normally I would also do it, but it can not be done to other causes. Can this be done via php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through two arrays and compare results to display results that do not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413936/iterate-through-two-arrays-and-compare-results-to-display-results-that-do-not-ma)

Comment: Okay @jvnill .. There is not accepted answer there either?

Answer (score 0):

Use php's array_dif() function. It compares 2 arrays and outputs stuff that doesn't match.  Its only a one way comparison though so you compare array 2 to array 1 and it spits out the differentials from array 1.
If you want to compare 1 to 2 then you have to run it the reverse way also.  Which will leave you with 2 output arrays.

You can then array_merge() the 2 together to give you one master array. Which is what you were looking for.

Ref:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Though you already have good hints how to solve this, there is another one.

```
    $array_a; // array 1
    $array_b; // array 2
    $array_c = array(); // result array

    function($array_a , $array_b) {
      foreach($array_a as $keya => $valuea) {

        foreach(array_b as $keyb => $valueb) {

                  if($valuea['city'] = $valueb['city']){
                        array_push($array_c, $array_b[$key]);
                  }
        }
      }
   }
```

This is not tested and from the top of my head.